# summing column by column in java

Tags: java, arrays, io

```
i have file txt in desktop :
1   5     23
2   5     25  
3   30    36

i want sum column by column 1 + 2 + 3 =... and 5 + 5...n and 23,...n

Scanner sc = new Scanner (file("patch");
while (sc.hasNextLine)
```

> {
>
> //each sum by column
>
> }
>
> help me please thanks

Comment: If you know how many entries there'll be on each line, you could make an `int[]` for the sums.  Then after you read each row, split it, parse it, and increment each individual sum.

Comment: @DavidWallace you could use a 2d array without knowing how many entries per line, but it gets more complicated.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus  You could, and you'd have to be a little bit insane.  If you don't know how many entries are on each line, you should be using an `ArrayList`, and a little bit of fancy logic around when to add a new entry to it.

Comment: a little bit insane or a little byte insane.  There are a lot of better ways of doing things besides an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to clean up my `Scanner` using the `File`. Also, you could construct a `Scanner` around the `line` of input to get your `int` columns (that doesn't need to be closed because `String`(s) aren't closable anyway). Something like,

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("patch"))) {
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner row = new Scanner(line);
        long sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (row.hasNextInt()) {
            int val = row.nextInt();
            if (count == 0) {
                System.out.print(val);
            } else {
                System.out.printf(" + %d", val);
            }
            sum += val;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(" = " + sum);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As the [`Scanner(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) Constructor Javadoc documents

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.

**Edit** To sum the columns is a little trickier, but you could read everything into a multidimensional `List<List<Integer>>` like

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("patch"))) {
    List<List<Integer>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    int colCount = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner row = new Scanner(line);
        colCount = 0;
        while (row.hasNextInt()) {
            colCount++;
            int val = row.nextInt();
            al.add(val);
        }
        rows.add(al);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (List<Integer> row : rows) {
            sum += row.get(i);
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
    System.out.println();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit 2** For efficiencies sake, you might prefer to use a `Map` like

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("patch"))) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> cols = new HashMap<>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner row = new Scanner(line);
        int colCount = 0;
        while (row.hasNextInt()) {
            int val = row.nextInt();
            if (cols.containsKey(colCount)) {
                val += cols.get(colCount);
            }
            cols.put(colCount, val);
            colCount++;
        }
    }
    for (int i : cols.values()) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
    }
    System.out.println();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Question is to sum up same column values. Not same row.

Comment: Doesn't seem very efficient, keeping the entire matrix in memory.  You only need to keep a running total of every column.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code. Please go through the comments. 
This is one way of doing for your **reference**. I want you to try other ways to improve your knowledge rather just using this code.

```
int sums[] = null;
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        String row = sc.next();// get first row
        String[] values = row.split(" ");// split by space
        if(null == sums)
        {
            sums = new int[values.length];// create sum array with first row size
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (String value : values)
        {
            sums[index] = sums[index]+Integer.parseInt(value);//adding current row value to current sum
            index++;
        }
    }
    if(null != sums)
    {
        int index=0;
        for (int sum : sums)
        {
            System.out.println("Sum of column "+index+" : "+sum);// Printing each column sum
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is CSV formatted, then split line by comma(",") and find number of columns based on split array length.

Like below:

```
String line = sc.next();
String[] lineArr = line.split(",");
int len = lineArr.length;
```

create array of arraylists of size len and store each column field in the respective arraylist.
finally, at the end apply sum on each arraylist to calculate sum of each column values.